# interface bmc280 & tsl2561 together

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I am trying to interface [`bme280`](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/products/all_products/bme280) & [`tsl2561`](https://www.adafruit.com/product/439) together with Pi Zero. I have connected `bme280` to Pi Zero on `Pin 3-I2C.1 SDA` & `Pin 5-I2C.1 SCL` and was able to read the data over `i2c`. Also want to add `tsl2561` to read LUX. Can I use `Pin 27-I2C.0 SDA` & `Pin 28-I2C.0 SCL` for `tsl2561`

Is it possible ?

Comment: What is a bmc280? If the devices use different I2C addresses that should be possible.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than one device can be used on a Pi I2C bus provided that:

1. They can be configured to have different I2C addresses.
2. They can operate with a 3V3 bus.
3. They do not have their own I2C pull-ups to more than 3V3 (ideally they should have no pull-ups at all).
4. They use 8-bit I2C addresses (the normal case, you rarely see 10-bit address devices).

If your devices do not meet any of 1-3 you could connect them via a bus multiplexer e.g. a [PCA9547](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9547.pdf).

If your devices do not meet 1 you could create a software I2C bus on any pair of spare GPIO and transfer the clashing device to that bus.  See `/boot/overlays/README` for details.  You would need to add your own pull-up resistors to 3V3 on the GPIO you use.  For reference the Pi uses 1k8 resistors on the hardware I2C bus on SDA and SCL.  You might get away with enabling the internal 50k pull-ups on the GPIO for testing purposes.